# Including country/region and discipline in Q&A for which it is relevant

Tags: discussion

Some issues are likely to be different for different countries and different disciplines, e.g.:

- funding,
- career path and opportunities,
- academic degrees,
- compulsory exams.

I think it is worth to encourage people to state is explicitly, both in their questions and their answers.

Answer (score 4):

This general theme has been covered in a bunch of different topics on meta at this point, but I think this one is worth an upvote. Much of the focus has been on avoiding localization in the *question*, or at least specifying what field/geography you're asking from.

It think there's an equal burden on the *answering* poster to make where they're coming from explicit. Our answers, even at their most biased, are colored by experience.